# how can i find a beautiful function wrapper

Tags: c++, pthreads, c++17

```cpp
typedef void (*void_proc)(void* parameter); 
void* parallel_init(void* dummy, int core_number);
int parallel_addtask(void* parallel_monitor, void_proc process, void *parameter);
int parallel_waittask(void* parallel_monitor, int task_id);
int parallel_uninit(void* parallel_monitor);

struct parallel_parameter {
    int end;
    int begin;
};

void process(void* parameter) {
    auto p = reinterpret_cast<parallel_parameter*>(parameter);
    // ur_function_name(p->begin, p-end);
}
```

above is a parallel library(c style) which i woule like to use. every time u call it, u should define a specific struct parameter, it is so annoying that i want implement a template function to mitigate the call steps and i try some kinds of methods to achieve this but failed.

```cpp
template<typename _function, typename... _parameter>
int parallel_executor(_function&& function, _parameter&&... parameter) {
    auto res = 0;
    parallel_parameter p[8]{0};
    auto body = [](void* para) -> void {
        auto p = reinterpret_cast<parallel_parameter*>(para);
        function(p->begin, p->end, std::forward<_parameter>(parameter)...)
    };
    auto parallel_handle = parallel_init(nullptr, 8);
    do {
        for (int i = 0;i < 8; ++i) {
            res = parallel_addtask(parallel_handle, body, static_cast<void*>(&p[i]));
            if (res != 0) break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            res = parallel_waittask(parallel_handle, i);
            if (res != 0) break;
        }
    } while (false);
    parallel_uninit(parallel_handle);
    return res;
}
```

this call is just simple to show my dilemma, when i use the `parallel_executor`, it turns out `session`cannot be accessed, because i am not specific the capture style, but when i change the body into below style, the `parallel_addtask` will not accept body function.

```cpp
auto body = [&](void* para) -> void {
    auto p = reinterpret_cast<parallel_parameter*>(para);
    function(p->begin, p->end, std::forward<_parameter>(parameter)...)
};
```

and now i am in this awkward position for a while.  below is the call style which i prefered.

```cpp
auto ret = parallel_executor(
    [](int begin, int end, int parameter_1, int parameter_2) {
        std::cout << begin << " ==> " << end << " ==> " << parameter_1 << std::endl;
    },
    100, // parameter_1
    200  // parameter_2
);
```

regarding the issue, i hope I have made myself clear. any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: first argument  IS NOT A FUNCTION,  so `bind` use is incorrect afaik. Lambda expression produces an object of unique class-type

Comment: Where do `begin` and `end` parameters come from? How does it work? How does `dummy` come into play? `static_cast<void*>(&p)` Do you pass a pointer to a structure created on the stack within loop block scope to a parallel running function?! Does the function copy the data?

Comment: Which is the expected lifetime of `parameter`? (your one stops before `parallel_waittask` which seems suspicious for me :/)

Comment: @KamilCuk yes,you are right, i pass an `stack variable` to a function, it is DANGEROUS. i write the sample code just to declare my situtaiton and i will repair it when i get some free time.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah， it is DANGEROUS. i will repair this error.

Comment: Unclear how you split task... `parallel_parameter` is zero initialized, and `parallel_addtask` so have same parameters.

Comment: it is a sample code, and i just want to know if it is possible to achieve my goal though `parallel_executor` function.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper might look like:

```
class ParrallelWrapper
{
public:
    ParrallelWrapper(int core_number) :
        parallel_monitor(parallel_init(nullptr, core_number))
    {}

    ParrallelWrapper(const ParrallelWrapper&) = delete;
    ParrallelWrapper& operator= (const ParrallelWrapper&) = delete;

    ~ParrallelWrapper() { parallel_uninit(parallel_monitor); }

    int AddTask(std::function<void()> f) {
        auto run_function = *[](void* f){
            (*reinterpret_cast<std::function<void()>*>(f))();
        };
        functions.push_back(std::make_unique<std::function<void()>>(f));
        return parallel_addtask(parallel_monitor, run_function, functions.back().get());
    }
    int Wait(int task_id) { return parallel_waittask(parallel_monitor, task_id); }
private:
    void* parallel_monitor = nullptr;

    // Ensure lifetime, and pointer consistence.
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::function<void()>>> functions;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dff16a5282b5275)

Answer (score 0):

With appropriate blanks for specifying `begin`, `end`, and the number of tasks, you can use something like

```
struct parallel_deleter {
  void operator()(void *m) const {parallel_uninit(m);}
};

template<class F,class ...TT>
int parallel_executor(F f,TT &&...tt) {
  constexpr auto p=+f;          // require captureless
  constexpr int n=/*...*/;
  std::unique_ptr<void,parallel_deleter> m(parallel_init(nullptr,n));
  struct arg {
    int begin,end;
    std::tuple<TT...> user;
  };
  std::vector<arg> v(n,{0,0,{tt...}});
  for(auto &x : v) {
    x.begin=/*...*/;
    x.end=/*...*/;
    if(const int res=parallel_addtask(m.get(),[](void *v) {
        const auto &a=*static_cast<arg*>(v);
        std::apply([&a](auto &...aa) {p(a.begin,a.end,aa...);},a.user);
      },&x)) return res;
  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    if(const int res=parallel_waittask(m.get(),i)) return res;
  return parallel_uninit(m.release());
}
```

This design relies on a captureless lambda being passed (so that `p` can be used inside the task lambda without capturing anything); if you need to support any callable, Jarod42's solution based on `std::function` is superior.

Comment: thanks @[Davis Herring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8586227/davis-herring), seems like there are some problem this section
```c++
std::apply([&a](auto &...aa) {p(a.begin,a.end,aa...);},a.user);
```

Comment: the sample implementation of pallel_*** function by @[Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42)
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dff16a5282b5275

Comment: @degawong: What “some problem”?  I tested it, albeit with a trivial definition of the `parallel_`* functions.

Comment: @[Davis Herring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8586227/davis-herring),the second parameter type of  `parallel_addtask` needs to be `void(void*)`，when we pass a `lambda`to it,  the `lambda`should be captureless, if the `lambda` is captureless, we can not use `p` into `lambda` i  think. my compile environment is `MSVC 2019 16.10`.

Comment: @degawong: I think that’s a compiler bug; you can try making it `static` to work around it.

Comment: @[Davis Herring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8586227/davis-herring),when i change the code into this, it works.`constexpr static auto p=f`in the original code, my main problem is the captureless lambda cannot accept my function and variadic parameters, if i have realized we can use the static temp variable`p`, the problem is just simply solved. the key word is `static/const`, thank you for your patience, thank you.